# Penrose's explanation of the two-slit experiment

Tags: quantum-mechanics, experimental-physics, double-slit-experiment, thought-experiment

I don't understand what Penrose is talking about in the following paragraph of his book "The Road To Reality". I have read about the two-slit experiment in other texts and I understand it (as much as could be understood!) but I think Penrose always has extra points; but I don't get this.

Section: "The ‘holistic’ nature of a wavefunction."

> There is something that should be emphasized here. One could imagine that a little spot on the screen comes about from time to time, when the local intensity of the wave reaches some critical value or, rather, that there is some probability of a little spot appearing on the screen, this probability increases as the intensity of the wave increases. Nice try! But as I have formulated the two-slit experiment (in its idealized form) above, this simply will not work. For if it were just a matter of individual probabilities at individual places, we should expect that sometimes two spots would appear on the screen, at widely separated locations where the intensity is appreciable, with just the one wavefunction describing the emission of a single particle at the source.

Comment: You can understand the 2 slit experiment if you believe that an excited electron in an atom/source is already interacting with the EM field .... long before photon emission (and eventual absorption).  Feynman and Dirac had better understandings (IMO) of the DSE ... they stated the photon interferes with itself .... the modern interpretation being that the the EM field is very dynamic and guides the energy. Penrose was famous with Hawking on black holes .... I don't really get what he's chatting about above .... I'd stick with Feynman and Dirac!

Answer (score 3):

Penrose is referring to the fact that with a single-particle wavefunction, if the screen lights up at one spot, it is *guaranteed* that it does not light up at any other. Even though the electron arrives at all points on the screen simultaneously, somehow, all the other parts of the screen know not to light up. There is no time for any light-speed signal from the point that lights up to reach the rest of the screen before the wave has passed and the decision made.

If physics is local (no faster-than-light signalling) and the decision whether to light up or not is made at the moment the wave hits the screen, then what stops the single particle appearing at two places on the screen at once? There is no way for either point to communicate its decision to the other, and no way for them to know until the electron gets there what *sort* of decision will need to be made - so how are they coordinated?

There are (at least) three conceivable ways out of this problem. The decision is made well *before* the electron hits the screen (the so-called 'hidden variables' thesis Einstein championed and which was refuted by Alain Aspect's demonstration of Bell's inequalities being violated), the decision is made *when* the electron hits the screen and the wavefunction collapse *does* propagate faster than light, which is the mainstream Copenhagen Interpretation, or *the decision is not made at all*, the screen lights up at *every point at once*, but the wavefunction of the observer observing it becomes correlated with the electron's spread-out wavefunction, evolving into a spread-out *superposition of mutually-invisible observers* who *each* see the screen light up at one point.

The third  option above is commonly (but inaccurately) called the 'Many Worlds Interpretation', because it is as if the observer splits across many independent 'worlds', with one possible outcome occurring in each. You never see the electron appearing in two places at once because the alternative outcomes and all the consequences that follow are forever separated by being in two of these different 'worlds'.

Strictly, the theory says there is only *one* world, but parts of it cannot see or interact with one another. It is like ripples on a pond crossing over one another. Each acts as if the other was not there, but there is only one pond, and one water surface they all share. For that reason, many prefer to call it the Everett Interpretation, but 'Many Worlds' is more popular.

Where Penrose says "For if it were just a matter of **individual probabilities at individual places**...", he means 'if physics is local'. If physics is local, and the decision is made when the electron hits the screeen, then we would expect to see the electron occasionally appearing in several places at once. We don't. So something stranger is going on.

The collapse of the wavefunction somehow happens to the whole wavefunction, all in one go. This is what he means by "holistic". It can't be broken down into parts acting independently.

Answer (score -1):

Think of air pressure. Classically, air is a continuous fluid that presses against the walls of the container. If you smoothly reduce the volume of a closed container, the pressure smoothly increases. If you blow air through a pipe, the pressure is a smooth function of position.

This sounds a lot like the intensity of light. Light is described classically by electric and magnetic fields, which are smooth functions of position. If you pass light through a double slit and light up a screen, intensity is a smooth function of position.

If you look at air microscopically, all this smoothness goes away. Air is made of molecules that bounce of the walls. Air pressure is made of individual discrete collisions. If you looked at one molecule at a time, you would see that air pressure at a point depends on how many collisions per second occur at that point. Individual collisions occur at random spots. If you have enough, they average out to a smoothly varying function.

Light is similar (thought not totally the same) when you look at it microscopically. It is made of individual photons that hit the screen at random spots. If you have a lot of photons, light is brightest where more photons per second hit. The wave function tells you where to expect a lot of photons per second.